# Make GridView fit its container/constraints

Tags: android, gridview, android-constraintlayout

I'm making small android memory game.
I've been troubling for a few hours with this issue, regarding GridView inside constraint layout. I'd want it to fit its constraints, without need to scroll.

Is there any way to  make the GridView completely fit inside the container, so the horizontal axis is going to be exact? Bottom edge should match `@+id/text_time` top edge. Internet and Stackoverflow are full of these examples, but for a ImageView.ScaleType.
Below is a short layout code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
tools:context="com.example.alen.matchinggameaddiko.activities.GameActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/gameLogoSize"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/gameLogoMarginLeft"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gameLogoMarginTop"
    android:src="@drawable/addiko_logo_white"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_game"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gameGridMarginTop"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/gameGridHorizontalSpacing"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/gameGridVerticalSpacing"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text_time"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/timerMarginBottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/timerMarginRight"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
    android:textSize="@dimen/timerTextSize"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

[Here is a photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwTEV.png). I draw a red line, so it's more clear where the GridView should end.
Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Have you tried putting your GridView inside of a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen your Layout.xml Try to set your GridView, Match_Parent in Both Width and Height. set `constraintEnd_toEndOf` and `toStartof` and `toTopof` and etc on `"parent"` For the GridView.

Then set those Textview and ImageView to be Aligned with the GridView.

What you've done is to set ImageView and TextView first then you Aligned GridView with them, What I'm Suggesting is Set your GridView to be Matched with Parent, Then put anything else Aligned with the GridView.

Also You must check if XML is not giving you any Warning for Height of the GridView. You may have to Set GridView Height to WRAP_PARENT. Just Check